# Value in div not showing

Tags: jquery, html

I am unsure what I am not getting a value showing my `.percentage` div that should be dynamically filled via jQuery.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var changedData = $('.changedData').val().length;
var originalData = $('.originalData').val().length;

var precentageOfChange = changedData/originalData * 100 - 100
$('.percentage').append(precentageOfChange);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="org">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Orginal Data</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <textarea class="orginalData"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
        <div class="changed">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Changed Data</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <textarea class="changedData"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="percentage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all you should need to run on jQuery ready. 
Put all code in 
$(document).ready(function(){       

})

Comment: Jess I have a feeling you are trying to append data to the page, "after" the user submits the form, or when he is off focus from the form input field after its filled out.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/pzV3u/1/)

Your code needs to be in a ready callback: as-is, the script is executed before the DOM elements are created, so they don't exist yet when you try to run this. Secondly, you should use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) not [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append). You're trying to set the `innerHTML`, not create a child element.

Use the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) to run this every time the values change.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.originalData').change(function () {
            $('.changedData').val($(this).val());
            $('.percentage').text('0%');

        });
        $('.changedData').change(function () {
            var changedData = $(this).val().length;
            var originalData = $('.originalData').val().length;

            var percentageOfChange = changedData / originalData * 100 - 100
            $('.percentage').text(percentageOfChange+'%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have updated my code but they are still not showing a value

Comment: i think you got it.  Jess didn't have the document.ready wrapping around his logic. good catch!

Comment: Jess i think its also because you need to initally load values when the page loads.

Comment: I am wanting to add content into the original data textarea and when I edit the content in the changed data textarea I want it to create a percentage of how much is changed starting from 0%

Comment: No sorry im still not getting a value and blachawk just confuses me haha